# Is it possible to make a root class to not have separate table for Entity Framework with TPT?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I has the following classes:

```
abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

abstract class Package : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("HourlyPackets")]
class HourlyPacket : Package
{
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to have only `Packages` and `HourlyPackets` tables. But from what I have read about TPT is its look like it will have `Entities` table too.

Is it possible to have only two tables that I want?

Comment: I think if you don't define `DbSet<Entity>` in your context, it will be treated simply as base class.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I have not tried what you told me. What I try is apply `MapInheritedProperties` on `Package` and its work. Maybe it does not matter because I'm lazy to remove `MapInheritedProperties` and see the results.